# DEM's from Baja, Mexico

Tags: dem, elevation, mexico

I need to extend my digital elevation map (10m or 30m will do) into Baja from southern CA.

Comment: For data requests, try [Open Data Stackexchange](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 2):

There is SRTM 1 arcsec (that is approx. 30m) global data (land between parallels 60N and 60S respectively) available to download from **https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/**.
Just click the location, follow to the another tab "Data Sets" and locate Digital Elevation -> SRTM -> SRTM 1 Arc-Second Global. Proceed to "Results" tab and follow the "Download" icon.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can download the DEMs included with ALOS PALSAR RTC products. These DEMs are what was used for RTC processing (usually from SRTM and NED, with a geoid correction applied). They have been resampled to a pixel spacing of 12.5m, but the actual resolution will vary depending on the DEM.

[image]